# Cannot extract version number of nginx using regex

Tags: regex, nginx, powershell-5.1

I am trying to extract out the version number of nginx by using regex on powershell. This is the code I tried.

```
(& nginx -v) -match "\d+\.\d+\.\d+"
```

This does not seem to work. I tried a similar thing with node.

```
(& node -v) -match "\d+\.\d+\.\d+"
```

In this case it spits out `True` and I do acquire the version number.

```
$Matches[0]     # 16.11.0
```

In fact I tried to match on the first character but it still didn't work.

```
(& nginx -v) -match "."
```

This does not spit out `True` or `False` as if I never passed the `-match` operator. I was also trying to match on the first line of the output and ended up with this line which does spit out something but it is `False`.

```
@(& nginx -v)[0] -match "."
```

I am using powershell version 5.1 and nginx version 1.23.1

What is so weird about nginx's output that powershell could not match on it? How can I get around this?

Comment: What is the output if you run `nginx -v` directly?

Comment: @knittl The output is ```nginx version: nginx/1.23.1```

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Thanks for replying. No, both of these don't work. In fact if you read my question even "." doesn't match.

Comment: I don't know powershell even remotely well enough, but perhaps the blanks are the problem? The version output of node doesn't have any spaces, but the nginx output does.

Comment: This works for python too! Try ``(& python --version) -match "\d+\.\d+\.\d+"``` the output python gives is ```Python 3.8.10``` and the version number does get matched

Comment: You have a typo, `ngnix`, you need to use `nginx`.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew sorry for the typo. It still does not work.

Comment: Is `nginx` listed in the `Path` environment variable? Try with the full path.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Yes it is. I do get the output on typing ```nginx -v``` which is ```nginx version: nginx/1.23.1```.

Comment: Try `(& nginx -v 2>&1) -match "\d+(?:\.\d+)+"` or `(& .\nginx -v 2>&1) -match "\d+(?:\.\d+)+"`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Yes, that's it! nginx prints its version info on stderr.

Comment: @knittl that's what `2>&1` does

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use

```
(& nginx -v 2>&1) -match "\d+(?:\.\d+)+"
```

That is, the version string is printed on the standard error stream. `2>&1` redirects it to standard output stream, and makes the text "regexable".

Comment: Thank you so much for the help [@Wiktor Stribizew](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3832970/wiktor-stribi%c5%bcew) and [@knittl](https://stackoverflow.com/users/112968/knittl)

Answer (score 0):

Or it looks like the output of cmd is all to 1 [stdout]
(vice versa is also true, cmd running powershell).  Replace everything before the slash with nothing.

```
# normally goes to stderr [2] - 'nginx version: nginx/1.23.1'

(cmd /c nginx -v) -replace '.*/'

1.23.1
```